# Why did I get suddenly more paragon?

Tags: kittens-game

I was playing kittens-game, and suddenly I noticed I had 3 paragon, instead of 1. I only reset once, over a month ago, and I had 1 paragon the whole time. I didn't do anything with the console, no jerking around with my savegame or anything. I can't find anything in the changelog that has anything to do with gaining paragon. Where does it come from?

(Bloodrizer, if you are reading this: please do not punish me and set me back to 1 paragon!)

Comment: I was typing the same question when I saw yours. I have never reset my game, and I just noticed I had 5 paragons with no reference in the log to where they came from

Comment: Seriously? Something strange is going on then. How far are you progressed in the game such that you get 5 paragon? I have 132 kittens and busy getting unobtanium and space missions (getting 65k + oil now)

Comment: Around the same place as you are. 128 kittens, 64.5k oil (soon 66k), 500+ unobtainium. I also noticed a BLS 1% to the left of ``save``. I'm in the middle of typing a question about that

Comment: Yep. That 1% BLS is also noted by me, it is because of sorrow. I cannot find anything about that in the rest of the code (only in game.js), so it is probably being build and should have an effect in further updates of the game

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of yesterday, bloodrizer made a change to award 1 paragon point per 1000 in-game years (about 9.26 real-time days). The changelog hasn't been updated; you'd only know about it [by checking the latest source code changes](https://bitbucket.org/bloodrizer/kitten-game).

Some people are reporting on reddit that they're receiving a point too early; that particular bug will probably get fixed soon.

Comment: Ahh, yes. Thanks. I am in year 2835, so it seems correct for me (2 paragon increase, 2 millennia spent)