# What is Black Liquid Sorrow?

Tags: kittens-game

I have noticed that a "BLS 1%" has appeared next to the Save button. It also coincided with a 3% decline in Happiness (196 to 193%), and the sudden appearance of 5 Paragons ([see this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/192120/77416)), though I had none and have never reset the game.

It's likely a new update, but has anyone looked at the code recently and can shed some light on what this variable does?

Comment: After reading this (and thus knowing there had been an update) I logged into Kittens Game and the first thing in my log was "Year 245, Winter: Black rain is falling over the village".  Thought you should know :D

Comment: @gatherer818 Thank you :). I must have missed it when I refreshed the page

Comment: There was a change where Paragon is set to the larger of previous Paragon and year number/1000.  I assume you're around 5000 years in?

Comment: @AaronDufour Yes, I'm around Year 5800. I spent those Paragons on the Metaphysics upgrade, but somehow I got 6 more of them today

Answer (score 8, accepted):

BLS is an indicator for how many nerfs your kittens have lived through. The latest change, which added the mechanic, also nerfed compendiums and zebras slightly; it's unclear which one counted here. With the current implementation, you only get one sorrow point even if multiple nerfs have occurred since your last time playing.

BLS doesn't actually have any in-game effect yet, but a guess is that it's been added due to [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/kittensgame/comments/2mk3w4/bonus_for_surviving_rebalancing/), where it was proposed to give a tiny boost to tear production. We don't know if that is what it will actually end up doing, though.

Comment: Interesting concept. Thank you for the explanation and the link. My maximum science also dropped substanially. That must be the compendium nerf you mentioned

Comment: @Timmy: The compendium nerf, specifically, is that they now only give +10; they were always intended to do that, but the effect was being applied twice.

Comment: What' a 'nerf'?

Comment: @bmargulies: A "nerf" refers any change which makes something less powerful than it used to be. [It is a common term in gaming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerf_(video_gaming)).

Answer (score 4):

The current accepted answer, written in 2014, is no longer correct.

BLS is a resource derived from unicorn tears used to build Black Pyramids.

For more details, [see the wiki](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Sorrow).