# I have paragon now?

Tags: kittens-game

I have opened the game with old save today to discover that my science cap has dropped from 1.7 M to 1.1 M and that I have 4 paragon now.

How did I get that 4 paragon? I never reset the game before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you get 1 paragon for 1000 years ingame time. The science drop is maybe because you converted some compendium to blueprint? See also [my question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/192120/why-did-i-get-suddenly-more-paragon) and the answer there.

Comment: The science cap drop was more likely because of the compendium nerf which was applied in the same update as the paragon-over-time.

Comment: @gatherer818 yes, you are right